# How to insert values into a form from another table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have two tables. A first table contains a list of offices and a second table contains a list of cartridges. When I create the cartridge, it's required to write the office. But it is necessary that in the form of creating a cartridge in the office selection there should be a list from the Office table. How to do it?

For example, there is the list:

```
Office
ID name
1 A11
2 A11-1
3 A12
4 A13
5 A13-2
```

My code:
Models.py

```
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('office_list')

class CartridgeList(models.Model):
    office = models.CharField('office', max_length=255)
    uniquenumber = models.CharField('unique number', max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField('status', max_length=255)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cartridge_list')
```

forms.py

```
class CartridgeListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartridgeList
        fields = ('office', 'uniquenumber', 'status')
        
        widgets = {
            # Now I write the office here, but it's required to have a ready list from Office Model (A11, A11-1, A12, A13, A13-2)
            'office': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'uniquenumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'status': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Views.py:

```
class AddCartridgeListView(CreateView):
    model = CartridgeList
    form_class = CartridgeListForm
    template_name = 'add_cartridge.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ChoiceField and limit the choices to those in the Office table

```
class CartridgeListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    office = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((name, name) for name in Office.objects.values_list("name", flat=True)))
    class Meta:
        model = CartridgeList
        fields = ('office', 'uniquenumber', 'status')
```

You'll need a Select as widget however

Comment: Thanks @Alombaros, I also find your suggestion helpful but what if I need this value as default without me selecting it.

Comment: I'm not sure of what value you want to use as default since there is a list of options. I'm pretty sure the first element will be the default one, you would need to add an ("------", None) element as first choice to implement the default Django behavior